# HEAP CORRPUTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#187)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, heap-corruption

Wrote a simple program. You write a number in the console and an array with the size of the number you wrote in is created and printed. I have now this error, heap corruption detected and I see no problems with my code so please help me out.

```
#include <iostream>

class dmas
{
public:
    int num;
    dmas(int size)
    {
        this->num = size;
    }
    int* a = new int[num];
    void logic()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
            }
            delete [] a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the massive" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> size;
    dmas a(size);
    a.logic();
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declaring member variable `int* a = new int[num];` doesn't magically make the member resize itself just because you later changed `num` in the constructor *after* member-initialization. Use a `std::vector`. It was literally made for this task. You should also be compiling with heightened warnings and treating them as errors, because that's exactly what they are. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/EvqoGW4Mo).

Comment: Consider [turning on your compiler's warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/GY3xrfzad).

Comment: What value do you think `this->a` has while `this->num = size;` is executing?

Comment: `this->a` has no value while `this->num = size;` is executed. But how is this gonna affect me if later I initialize `this->a` with `new int[num];`?

Comment: @asapRichi I have the feeling you used C++ in a datastructures class, but no you really should only use new/delete in rare cases now. And you really should start using std::vector (or any of the other STL containers). [An introduction to std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/). And if you really are going to allocate memory yourself, use std::make_unique. Also try to avoid any of the old style "C" headers, for random generation look at #inlcude <random>.

Comment: @asapRichi Why would it have no value? What if you wanted to do `a[0] = 3;`? Would that be illegal? What if you called `logic()` right after that line?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this initialization of the pointer a

```
class dmas
{
public:
    int num;
    dmas(int size)
    {
        this->num = size;
    }
    int* a = new int[num];
    //...
```

The call of the operator new occurs when the variable `num` is default initialized and has no yet the value of the parameter size assigned to it in the body of the constructor.

At least you need to write

```
    dmas(int size) : num( size )
    {
    }
```

Pay attention to that the call of operator `delete []`

```
delete [] a;
```

you should move from the function `print` to the class destructor.

Comment: I don't get why doesn't  `this->num = size;` initialize num with size? What does it do then?

Comment: @asapRichi The both data members num and a are created before the body of the constructor gets the control. So the data member num has an indeterminate value when the operator new is called.  When the data member num is placed in the mem-initializer list of the constructor then it is created using the initializer size and this initialized data member is used in the call of the operator new.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the value of `num` at the allocation.

I added a function

```cpp
int printNum(int num) {
    std::cout << "num = " << num << std::endl;
    return num;
}
```

and changed the allocation

```cpp
    int* a = new int[num];
```

to

```cpp
    int* a = new int[printNum(num)];
```

This resulted in `num = 0` being printed despite of I entered `10` for the standard input.

Now you can see the value of `num` set in the constructor is not used here.

To fix this, you can use member initializer:

```cpp
    dmas(int size) : num(size)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate any memory at all, because this `int* a = new int[num];` is outside the scope of your constructor!

To make it work, replace this piece of code:

```
public:
    int num;
    dmas(int size)
    {
        this->num = size;
    }
    int* a = new int[num];
```

with this:

```
public:
    int num;
    int *a;
    dmas(int size)
    {
        this->num = size;
        a = new int[num];
    }
```

Then should work fine!